# jQuery 'on' click not checking for updated selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a simple button (sort of) for a user to iterate through a number of selections when clicking "up" or "down".

I'm using jQuery to check after each click that there are more things up (or down) and updating the classes / styles / selections accordingly. However if I change the class of the element that is triggering the "on" function, it is still triggering (on click) even though all the classes specified in the selector are not there (in the DOM) any more.

In this simplified example if you click the "i.up.enabled" element then it's class switches ".up.disabled" and the visible field changes. Fine so far. However, if you click it again then it updates again, which it shouldn't(?) as the selector used to call the 'on' function is "i.up.enabled" and not "i.up.**disabled**". It's reasonably simple to work round this but I wondered why this is?

Does "on" read from the source rather than the DOM & is there a more accepted way doing this?

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div data-state="1">Number 1</div>
    <div data-state="0">Number 2</div>
    <i class="up enabled">up</i>
</div>
```

CSS

```
i {
    cursor: pointer;
}
div[data-state="0"] {
    display: none;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
div[data-state="1"] {
    padding: 0 2rem;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
.wrapper > * {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 90%;
}
i.disabled {
    color: gray;
    cursor: default;
}
i.enabled {
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript / jQuery

```
$('.wrapper i.enabled.up').on('click', function(){
    var $current = $(this).siblings('div[data-state="1"]');
    var $next = $(this).siblings('div[data-state="0"]');
    $current.attr('data-state', 0)
    $(this).addClass('disabled').removeClass('enabled');
    $next.attr('data-state', 1);
});
```

[And the fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/8h3zoqtn/3/)

N.B. I appreciate that .data() is better for manipulating data-* elements, but due to restrictions I have to use attr("data-*", [value])

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: you are only adding class `disabled` not `attribute` `disabled`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

Its does't matter even if selector is modified, Event will still be attached with these elements when using "direct" binding.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically or manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes).

*General Syntax*

```
$(staticParentElement).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', 'i.enabled.up', function(){   
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/zq7tqtuo/)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the event inside the `on` function using `$(this).off("click");`:

```js
$('.wrapper i.enabled.up').on('click', function(e) {
  var $current = $(this).siblings('div[data-state="1"]');
  var $next = $(this).siblings('div[data-state="0"]');
  $current.attr('data-state', 0)
  $(this).addClass('disabled').removeClass('enabled');
  $next.attr('data-state', 1);
  $(this).off("click");
});
```

```css
i {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div[data-state="0"] {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

div[data-state="1"] {
  padding: 0 2rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.wrapper > * {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 90%;
}

i.disabled {
  color: gray;
  cursor: default;
}

i.enabled {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div data-state="1">Number 1</div>
  <div data-state="0">Number 2</div>
  <i class="up enabled">up</i>
</div>
```